# How to configure second wireless router via VLAN trunk?

Tags: networking, vlan, dhcp-server, trunk

I am trying to figure how to configure the second wireless router, but I got stuck while trying to get the following configuration:

1. For all VLANs (0-3), the primary router is the DHCP server for IPv4 while the secondary router is the DHCP server for IPv6.
2. The two routers are connected via a VLAN trunk.
3. One of the four ports of the secondary router that a server is connected to must be made as a VLAN trunk port.
4. All access points of the secondary router is bridged to VLAN 1 only.

How do I configure the secondary router for the above to work if the primary router is running Tomato while the secondary router is running DD-WRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you know how to configure the ports and the vlans so the question here really comes down to '*How can DHCP requests from different VLANs reach my DHCP servers?*' You need to configure an ipv4-helper-address and an ipv6-helper-address on all vlans 0-3 where the v4- is the IP of R1 and v6- is R2.